# Minimum sum of squared Euclidean distance between two arrays

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Question:**

Given two sorted sequences in increasing order, X and Y.

Y is of size k and X is of size m.

I would like to take a subset of X i.e. **X' of size k**, and consider the following optimization problem:

```
d(Y,X') =   sum ( (Y[j] - X'[j])^2) for j in [1,k]:;
```

X' is the subset of X with size k,

Y[j] and X'[j] is element in Y and X',

I want to find the subset of X, to reach the minimum of d(Y, X').

d(Y, X') is the sum of the squared distance between elements in Y and X'.

Note that X' could have k! numbers of rearrangements, so its order is totally unknown.

I want to utilize DP approach to solve this problem.

---

*My thought so far:*

I plan to go over all the element in Y and compute their squared distance with each element in X. But I'm totally at lost with what to do next.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of what you asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930579/dynamic-programming-finding-the-minimum-sum-of-euclidean-distance-between-two-a

Comment: @Elliott that's true, but that question have been closed.

Comment: Did you read the feedback as to why? You're question isn't specific. You've copied your homework question into here and are just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: @Elliott well I'm not asking anyone to do that, I'm just trying to reach out to see if anyone happens to know problems like that.

Comment: This website is design to help you with specific well-researched problems, where questions are written and formatted properly to help the reader. Please read How To Ask a Question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think to be fair to the OP, he's asking the right way to approach this DP. Btw may I suggest posting the question to https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: @SerialLazer, if you look at the question from yesterday it was blatantly asking for the solution, and moreover it was too broad and was appropriately closed. The question today is exactly the same, except now it's unspecific.

Comment: @Elliott I agree the quality of the qn can be improved

Comment: @SerialLazer, Especially as homework questions have some extra non-formal rules (which I certainly agree with): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8658157

Comment: Voting to close this question since it appears here [https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132523/minimum-sum-of-squared-euclidean-distance-between-two-arrays](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132523/minimum-sum-of-squared-euclidean-distance-between-two-arrays)